# Hamming Code Problem

Tags: coding-theory

I have a binary code $001011100000101100110$ which has a mistake and using Hamming Code. I need to fix this binary code and solve which hidden word is in this $001011100000101100110$.

Position $1$ checks $1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21$
Position $2$ checks $2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15,18,19$
Position $4$ checks $4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15,20,21$
Position $8$ checks $8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15$
Position $16$ checks $16,17,18,19,20,21$

I found an error in the main digits, namely in the second and sixteenth, and I can not decode the word

Comment: Presumably this is a _shortened_ $[21, 16]$ nonsystematic Hamming code, shortened from the standard $[31,26]$ Hamming code. The code cannot correct two errors, and if you found that the 2nd and 16th bits are in error (_How_ did you determine this? by the way), there is most likely a single bit error that will produce the same syndrome.

Comment: Repeating the comment from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80472/11619): you haven't told us *which* Hamming code is used. Presumably Dilip got it right, and the bits are in standard order. Are what you call *Position 1,2,4,8,16* to be the rows of a parity check matrix?